# How to use bash script for obtaining only lines in FILE B that are different from another FILE A?

Tags: bash, compare, comparison

I am trying to use bash script for doing this thing but I can't do that.

These are my data.

File A:

43477     102531     114783      4.115     -1.748     11.127      5.587
 41777      50955      84639     -4.310     -0.091     10.786     -3.910
 41777      44259      65661     -2.176     -0.615      4.667     -2.365
 43477     102531     114783      4.115     -1.748     11.127      5.587

File B:

43477     102531     114783      4.115     -1.748     11.127      5.587
 45777     117537      87933     -0.796     -1.043      5.087     -1.581
 48977      88665      56952     -2.188     -0.919      4.310     -2.523
 41777      50955      84639     -4.310     -0.091     10.786     -3.910
 49577      69957      97128     -1.940     -1.209      4.153     -1.680
 41777      44259      65661     -2.176     -0.615      4.667     -2.365
 47977      98640      88665     -1.894     -0.800      4.032     -2.315
 41777      44259      65661     -2.176     -0.615      4.667     -2.365

I want to obtain something like,

FINAL:

45777     117537      87933     -0.796     -1.043      5.087     -1.581
 48977      88665      56952     -2.188     -0.919      4.310     -2.523
 49577      69957      97128     -1.940     -1.209      4.153     -1.680
 47977      98640      88665     -1.894     -0.800      4.032     -2.315

**Print only the lines containing in FILE B that are different form FILE A, and if there are duplicate lines, print it only one of them using bash script.**

Thank you

Comment: I recommend that you search for this, there are countless examples of "print difference between two files" and "print first occurrence of each line".

Comment: I think the example is incorrect: for example the first line in file A and B is the same but is not part of the output even if you ask "...if there are duplicate lines, print it only one of them..."

Anyway you can check [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11343/linux-tools-to-treat-files-as-sets-and-perform-set-operations-on-them) and you will find what are you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A hash_a hash_b
IFS="\n"

while read line; do
    hash_a[$line]=1
done < File_A

while read line; do
    hash_b[$line]=1
done < File_B

for i in ${!hash_b[@]}; do
    if [ -z "${hash_a[$i]}" ]; then
        echo $i
    fi
done
```

The trick is that an associative array automatically unifies the identical lines by using the whole line as a key.

Comment: Thank you very much @tshiono